# Pydev debugger throws syntax error after providing input

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, syntax-error, pydev

I am using Eclipse Mars 2, Pydev 5.1.2, Python 3.5. I wrote a simple code to get the number of lists to be passed (variable `num`), and print each subsequent input as a list of integers:

```
num=int(input())    #taking the no of lists to be inputted
n=[]                #stores the elements in each list

for i in range(0,num):  #iterating over the test cases
    n = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    print("n: ",n)
```

I put a breakpoint on the `for` loop. When i debug the program, after entering the "number of lists", when I enter the actual elements of the list, and press "Enter", I get a syntax error, as follows:

[image]

[image]

The program is executing fine. I am getting this error only while debugging.

Please help me understand the cause of this.

: Console output, as requested by Michael:

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 4172)
2
2 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\software\dev tools\eclipse\eclipse-jee-neon-2-win32\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.5.0.201701191708\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 354, in evaluate_expression
    compiled = compile(expression, '<string>', 'eval')
  File "<string>", line 1
    2 1
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\software\dev tools\eclipse\eclipse-jee-neon-2-win32\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.5.0.201701191708\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1122, in do_it
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluate_expression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "E:\software\dev tools\eclipse\eclipse-jee-neon-2-win32\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.5.0.201701191708\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 356, in evaluate_expression
    Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "E:\software\dev tools\eclipse\eclipse-jee-neon-2-win32\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.5.0.201701191708\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<string>", line 1
    2 1
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you paste the first error in as text so it's easier to see.

Comment: I am still not able to understand the cause of this error. Can anyone provide any leads on this? it has been almost 2 months now....

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to the latest version.

This was fixed in 5.4.0.

From the release notes (taken from http://www.pydev.org/history_pydev.html):

**Debugger**: When the user is waiting for some input, it'll no longer try to evaluate the entered contents.

Comment: I updated Eclipse Neon 2 (4.6.2), Pydev 5.5.0, Python 3.6. But I am still facing the same issue.